# How to find out the classes of a data.frame

Tags: r, class

I've a simple question which makes me weird this morning. How can I get a vector showing the classes of columns of a dataframe?

When I compute this I thought it should work, but it doesn't. I were even more surprised of the result and didn't understand the result.

Here is my example:

```
Example = data.frame(
             Col1 = c(2,5,10), 
             Col2 = c("Hello", "I am a", "Factor"), 
             Col3 = c(T,F,T))
str(Example)
# 'data.frame': 3 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ Col1: num  2 5 10
# $ Col2: Factor w/ 3 levels "Factor","Hello",..: 2 3 1
# $ Col3: logi  TRUE FALSE TRUE
```

So I have got a data frame with one numeric column, one factor column and one logical column and the result of the `class()` command in the apply function is `character`. Can anybody explain me why and how I can get a vector of the classes?

```
apply(Example, 2, class)
#       Col1        Col2        Col3 
# "character" "character" "character"
```

Comment: Okay, thanks sapply works. I'm just still wondering where the character expression come from in this apply call. But for the moment, it works.

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer as I might have a clue why this is the case - approved by a new answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`apply` doesn't work for you because, as in the docs:

```
 If ‘X’ is not an array but an object of a class with a non-null
 ‘dim’ value (such as a data frame), ‘apply’ attempts to coerce it
 to an array via ‘as.matrix’ if it is two-dimensional (e.g., a data
 frame) or via ‘as.array’.
```

so your data frame becomes a matrix with the column classes set to the simplest possible class that can represent your columns - in this case a character matrix:

```
> as.matrix(Example)
     Col1 Col2     Col3   
[1,] " 2" "Hello"  " TRUE"
[2,] " 5" "I am a" "FALSE"
[3,] "10" "Factor" " TRUE"
```

Use `sapply`

```
> sapply(Example,class)
     Col1      Col2      Col3 
"numeric"  "factor" "logical"
```

Answer (score 1):

I cannot actually explain it in detail, but you might try `sapply(Example, class)` to get the correct vector you're looking for. `sapply` is for dataframes, which is why it works. You can also use `lapply(Example, class)`, but you'll have to convert the list you get into a vector. This works too because most basically a dataframe is just a list of dataframes.

`apply` does not work because it's meant to be used on matrices. And as matrices are always of data from the same type, `apply` has to give you "character" as an answer. This is because once you have a single character in a given matrix (or a given vector), every number is also converted to character. This is the reason why `apply` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to loop for each column of you data frame

```
class.vec <- c()
for(c in colnames(Example)){
  class.vec <- c(class.vec, class(Example[[c]]))
}
class.vec
```

This will return:

```
> class.vec
[1] "numeric" "factor"  "logical"
```

A more "elegant" way is by using **sapply**:

```
class.vec <- sapply(Example, class)     
Col1      Col2      Col3 
    "numeric"  "factor" "logical"
```